# Failed to open stream. No such file or directory only in __destruct()

Tags: php, oop, simplexml

I am making a class to writing a xml file. I want to load the file in `__construct()` and save the file in `__destruct()`. But I am getting an error `Failed to open stream. No such file or directory` when I saving the xml in `__destruct()`. But I have created a manual function `close()` and save the xml file in it. error disappeared. What is the different between `__destruct()` and `close()` in file handling?

**My Code**

writemyxml.class.php:-

```
class writeMyXml{
  protected simpleXml;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->simpleXml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/my/file/file.xml');
  }

  // Writing functions goes here... (Not deleting the file)
  /*
  public function close(){
    $this->simpleXml->asXml('path/to/my/file/file.xml');
  }
  */
  public function __destruct(){
    $this->simpleXml->asXml('path/to/my/file/file.xml');
  }
}
```

test.php:-

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoloader.php";

$myxmlfile = new writeMyXml();

//Writing codes goes here

//$myxmlfile->close() Works with no errors

// Getting an error when using the __destructor() function
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) states:

> The working directory in the script shutdown phase can be different
>   with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).

This means that if you use the relative path to your file it will resolve to different paths in `close()` and `__destruct()`. If this is, indeed, the case you can set real path in the `__construct()` and use it:

```
class writeMyXml
{
    private $filename;

    protected $simpleXml;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = realpath($filename);

        $this->simpleXml = simplexml_load_file($this->filename);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->simpleXml->asXml($this->filename);
    }
}
```